# Multi level regression with interaction using R lme4

Tags: r, regression, interaction, multilevel-analysis

I'd like to do a regression analysis with interactions, my data has two levels (school classes and pupils). My variables are: Predictor = dummy variable on Level 1, dependent Variable = metric on level 1, moderator variable = metric, Level 2

I used the following command, but I am not sure if that right:

`model <- lmer(DV ~ 1 + IV1 + IV2 + IV1 * IV2 + (1|cluster), daten)`

Can you tell me if that's correct?

Answer (score 3):

Your formula:

`DV ~ 1 + IV1 + IV2 + IV1 * IV2 + (1|cluster)`

It says that you want to model your `DV` using fixed efffects of `IV1`, `IV2` and their interaction (`IB1:IV2`), and you want a random intercept therm for all `cluster`'s.

However, it is a little bit redundant since `+1` means "don't drop the intercept" what is default and `IV1 * IV2` translates to `IV1 + IV2 + IV1 : IV2`, so `IV1 + IV2` is redundant. It could be simplified to:

`DV ~ IV1 * IV2 + (1|cluster)`

If you would like to add an random slope (let's say `IV2`) for your clusters, then you would have to change the formula to:

`DV ~ IV1 * IV2 + (1 + IV2|cluster)`

For more information check [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.5823.pdf).